# Blog Tagline vs Headline in Django Sample

Tags: django, django-models, blogs

The Official Django 1.10 documentation gives an example of a models.py for a blog app with the following,

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tagline = models.TextField()

class Entry(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

My question is what is the difference between the tagline and headline?

Why give an Entry a name and tagline through the Blog model?

It appears that `blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen the Django Docs tutorial for 1.10. But, in general, that would mean that one blog can have multiple entries. For eg:

**BLOG:**

1. a) Blog Name: "SO is great"

b) Blog Tagline: "Hey, I wish SO was the primary mode of education in schools......"

**ENTRY:**

i)

a) Blog: FK to 1

b)Headline: "This is the usefulness of SO"

ii)

a) Blog: FK to 1

b) Headline: "This explains how SO can revolutionize education."

I hope I was able to make my points clear.